# Eclipse shows false semantic errors in cocos2d-x inline functions (ccc3 / ccc4)

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x

I have this code:

```
auto pLabel = CCLabelTTF::create("Test", "Arial", 24);
auto pLabel->setColor(ccc3(0,0,0));
```

And my Eclipse shows these markers on the second line:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void setColor(const cocos2d::_ccColor3B &) '
    - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: cocos2d::_ccColor3B ccc3(?, ?, ?) '
```

These are not real errors, I mean, I can build the project without problems so it has to be some kind of Eclipse-related mistake.

ccc3 is an inline function:

```
static inline ccColor3B
ccc3(const GLubyte r, const GLubyte g, const GLubyte b)
{
    ccColor3B c = {r, g, b};
    return c;
}
```

And if I rewrite the code in this way:

```
ccColor3B c3 = { 0, 0, 0 };
this->pLabel->setColor(c3);
```

The "error" is gone, so I guess it's related with the way Eclipse analyses the code, but I'm not able to find out what the exact problem is or how to solve it (or at least, how to make my Eclipse ignores it)

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable `Syntax and Semantic Errors` in eclipse. Until you have setup all correct include paths you won't get anything right. And if still eclipse warns or shows errors then you can simply disable them.

Go to

`Right Click Project -> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis -> Syntax and Semantic Errors`

Uncheck the option.

Comment: I need the error checking, it's quite hard to code without it. I just want to disable this specific check or make Eclipse analyses this inline functions in the right way.

Comment: Just for future reference, the check which produces this error is called "Invalid arguments", so uncheck it for a temporally solution. Anyway I'm still looking for a better way to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes there are many options you can explicitly disable what you wants.

Comment: Disabling the error checking is not a solution at all.We must fix the problem.I am stuck at this point as well and looking for solution.

Comment: You can use like. `ccColor3B color = { 0, 0, 0 };`